# Installing bootstrap using bower-installer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install bootstrap 3.3.5 in my solution using [bower-installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer)... I want to pull just distribution files (in dist folder) instead of everything that you get by doing `bower install bootstrap#3.3.5`.

However, bower.json in bootstrap 3.3.5 has these lines:

```
"main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

Thus, when I run `bower-installer` it copies just those two files. How do I configure `bower-installer` to copy all files from `/components/bootstrap/dist` so that I have all needed files (css, fonts, js)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this has already been discussed on some of the closed issues on GitHub:

- [Bower Installer and
  Paths](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer/issues/110)
- [Specify install
  folders](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer/issues/41)

After little experimentation I've got lucky using `/**` so my config looks like:

```
"install": {
    "path": "bower_dist",
    "sources": {
        "bootstrap": [
            "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**"
        ]
    }
}
```

This preserves folder structure results in separate `css`, `fonts`, `js` folders within `/bower_dist/boostrap/` with all needed files.